# PLC ladder diagram

Tags: plc

[PLC LADDER (RUNNING IN SIMULATION MODE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSYwT.png)

In ladder network 3 and 4, K3 is constantly on though no input is on (you can see plc config in right side). One reason may be that I have used NC of S5 in network 2 and S5 (NO) is directly connected to S3 in network 4. But since LD is top to down approach each network should be independent of others. Kindly provide me a solution.

Comment: Try the Electrical Engineering stack exchange?

Answer (score 0):

K3 is getting turned on in some other part of the program.  Under `Project` you can select `Show Cross Reference..` to see all the places you are using that variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use normal coil instead of set and reset coils.
You can only use once a same normal coil through all your ladder.
If you use K3 as normal coil only the latest use will be relevant, all other cases are overridden. It's like you say it to be OFF, and then say it to be ON. Only the latest one will have effect.
If you intend to use it as toggle, you should use "Set" and "Reset" coils. Set coils will set the relay until reset is commanded. Reset coil will reset the relay until set is commanded. If both actions are valid in one scan, latest of the actions will take effect. You can use as many set and reset commands to one coil as you like, but make sure they are momentary and do not interfere one with other.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that all what you put on the left side of your network are inputs. All stuff on the right are outputs.

So it's no problem to have different uses of inputs, it is common used actually! When you trigger S5 you will activate the outputs in network 3, and deactivate the timer in network 2.

Reason why K3 is powered is somewhere else, not visible on the current print screen.